# Is minimising the number of Include directives in Apache config faster?

Tags: apache

In my Apache config file for domains hosted on my site, I have a couple of Include directives containing redirects:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  Include /path/redirects1.conf
  Include /path/redirects2.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Would it be (appreciably) faster to combine these files into one file and so one Include directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only makes a difference whilst reading (or re-reading) the config files. Unless you do that *a lot* do what ever is most natural and easiest to maintain.